# How To Stop Node Downloading File Completely

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am Trying to do a Hobby Project in React and Node as part of my learning. In this project I am trying to convert http and https links to torrent. The problem i am facing is when i submit a link it downloading the complete file to the system and then converting it. How to avoid that. Here is my Code

```
var http = require('http');
var webtorrentify = require('webtorrentify-link');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
var path = require('path');
var validUrl = require('valid-url');
var express = require('express');
var getUrls = require('get-urls');
var remote = require('remote-file-size');
var app = express();

var downloadLink;
var fileName;
var fileSize;
var server;
var parsed;
var param;
var link;
var port;
port = process.env.PORT || 80;

app.get('/favicon.ico', function (req, res) {
  console.log('favicon request recived');
});
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/') {
    // app.use('/public/html', express.static(path.join(__dirname)));
    fs.readFile('public/html/index.html', function (err, data) {
      res.write(data);
    });
  } else if (req.url === '/l?thelink=') {
    fs.readFile('public/html/emptyRequest.html', function (err, data) {
      res.write(data);
      res.end();
    });
  } else {
    // ---------Reciving Url--------------------
    console.log(req.query.thelink);
    downloadLink = req.query.thelink;
    // -----------------------------------------

    // ------------checking for valid url-------
    if (validUrl.isUri(downloadLink)) {
      console.log('Looks like an URI');
      // -----------------------------------------

      // ----------Extracting filename-------------
      parsed = url.parse(downloadLink);
      fileName = path.basename(parsed.pathname);
      console.log(path.basename(parsed.pathname));
      // -------------------------------------------

      // ----------Finding File size----------------
      remote(downloadLink, function (err, o) {
        fileSize = (o / 1024) / 1024;
        console.log('size of ' + fileName + ' = ' + fileSize + ' MB');
        // -------------------------------------------
        if (fileSize < 501) {
          /// ////////////Creating Torrent////////////////////
          webtorrentify(downloadLink)
            .then(function (buffer) {
              console.log('creating the torrent');
              // res.send('what is');
              // -------------------------------------------
              res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-bittorrent');
              res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `inline; filename="${fileName}.torrent"`);
              res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=2592000'); // 30 days
              res.send(buffer);
              console.log(fileName + '.torrent created');
              res.end();
              // -------------------------------------------
            });
          /// /////////////////////////////////////////////
        } else {
          console.log('More than 500 MB');
          res.send('<h4> More than 500 MB or invalid URL </h4>');
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log('not url');
      fs.readFile('public/html/404.html', function (err, data) {
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
      });
    }
  }
});

app.listen(port);

console.log('server up and running', port);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is normal as documented in [webtorrentify-link's documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webtorrentify-link):

> This module will take a download URL and convert it into a .torrent file. Warning: it downloads the URL in order to do this.

And technically no module/code will be able to generate the torrent without downloading. This is because the [torrent file structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file#File_structure) requires each file pieces' hash, which can only be obtained and calculated having the full file.

Comment: thanks for the replay.. Is there any way to show th e sownloading of the file and then start torrentifying it

Comment: you can look for code snippets that can download and stream file output with progress, then you can use [create-torrent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-torrent) to generate the torrent, which webtorrentify-link is based on.

Comment: When I try to convert larger files (For example 1GB file), The app is crashing ... can u please tell me how to fix this